# Use keyboard for accessing Emacs Menu

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar, emacs

I am using the

```
brew install emacs
```

version of gui-based emacs.  After using the mac shortcut to access the Menu bar, I am able to use the mnemonic to access the individual top level menu items: e.g.

```
  ALT-F  for file
```

The problem is that then hitting down arrow key or return does not dropdown the menu items.   Well .. with two exceptions: the

> ```
> Alt-E (Emacs) and 
> Alt-H (Help)
> ```

dropdowns actually work.  The others? Nothing happens. Only by using the Mouse (which is unacceptable to me for common commands in an editor).

Any hints/ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good workaround in emacs (beta) forum:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3911/access-menu-bar-using-keyboard-on-mac-os-x

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-<f2>")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (x-popup-menu (list '(0 0) (selected-frame))
                  (mouse-menu-bar-map))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which Emacs you are using, but if it is GNU Emacs, at least, you should be able to use library [**La Carte**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaCarte), which gives you complete access to all of the menu-bar menus using the keyboard. You can match the complete path to a menu item deep in a submenu, etc. The source code is here:[**`lacarte.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/lacarte.el).